# How to replace conditional operator by && and ||?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, boolean-logic, conditional-operator

I'm working on [Expression parser](https://github.com/jcubic/expression.php) and I would like add conditional operator (`?:`) I've changeed `&&` and `||` to act like the onces in javascript, using this code:

```
case '&&':
    $stack->push($op1 && $op2 ? $op2 : ($op1 ? $op2 : $op1)); break;
case '||':
    $stack->push($op1 ? $op1 : $op2); break;
```

so I thought that I just replace `foo ? bar : baz` by `foo && bar || baz` is it possible using regex? if operators can be nested, each argument to conditional operator can have same operator.

Comment: you can but regex dont understand parenthesis so it will work only if you have varriable not complexe expression

Comment: not test it it will probably not work but it can help you s.replace(/(.*?)[?](.*?)[:](.*?) /g,function(match,$1,$2){
 return $1 + '&&' + $2 + '||' + $3;
})

Comment: The condition can exist in each part `here ? here : here`. So each part must be parsed as `condition ? yes-this : no-this` parsing parenthesis and `?` and `:` operators. Yes, this can be done using php regex since it supports recursion, but I doubt somebody would do this for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo && bar || baz` and `foo ? bar : baz` are not equivalent.

Suppose both `foo` is a value considered to be true and `bar` is a value considered to be false. In that case, `foo && bar` is false, so the value of the first expression is `baz`. The ternary operator (`?:`), on the other hand, alwys returns the second argument when the first argunent is true, so it will return `bar`.

Try `1 && 0 || 2` and `1 ? 0 : 2`. The first is 2 and the second 0.

The simplest way to evaluate the ternary operator is as a single operator taking three operands

---

By the way, `op1 && op2` could be written much more simply as `op1 ? op2 : op1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi!**
You can replace the `foo ? bar : baz;` with `foo && bar;` if and only if `baz === null`,
where `bar` is an expression, always resulting true.

> For eg. `bar = "this string is always gonna result true";`

Similarly, you can use `||` in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, you're mistaken as you can see ternary operatory has `baz` your code does not.